# git merge --no-commit creates a merge commit when run in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-merge, git-for-windows

I'm trying to merge `master` branch to my `feature` branch using IntelliJ IDEA's UI option. `VCS -> Git -> Merge Changes...`.

I select the checkbox `No commit` and select the `origin/master` branch to merge.

However, after doing this and I run `git log` I see that a new `commit` was created with the merged changes.

The same happens if I use the `Terminal` window in IntelliJ by running

`git merge origin/master --no-commit`.

When I do this in `Git Bash` it works correctly (the commit is not created).

Is there any known issue related to this problem with IntelliJ?

My IntelliJ IDEA version is: 2017.1.1 (build 171.4073.35)

Comment: I tried but did not reproduce it. The working tree and the index were updated but the commit was not made.

Answer (score 0):

GitBash is not a proper test here, cause it is not native bash for Windows, and commands issued by IDE are executed in another environment, not Git bash.

Check the result of `git merge origin/master --no-commit` executed in Windows command prompt. It is used by the IDE terminal by default.

BTW, --no-commit works fine for me.